# How to ascendingly order a to do list based on priority

Tags: python, sorting, command-line-interface, typer

So as part of an internship opportunity, we have been told to make a to-do list CLI app. The thing is I don't know how to sort the text in the file in ascending order of priority, any help would be appreciated

heres my code:

```
import typer 
app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def help():
    print("""Usage :-
$ ./todo add 2 hello world  # Add a new item with priority 2 and text "hello world" to the list
$ ./todo ls               # Show incomplete priortiy list items sorted by priority in ascending order
$ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete the incomplete item with the given priority number
$ ./todo done NUMBER      # Mark the incomplete item with given PRIORITY_NUMBER as complete
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
$ ./todo report           # Statistics """)


@app.command()
def add(priority: int,task: str):

    file1=open("ls.txt","r")
    x=len(file1.readlines())
    y=x+1
    file1.close()
    file1=open("ls.txt","a")
    file1.write(str(y)+". "+task + " ["+str(priority)+"]"+ "\n")
    file1.close()


@app.command()
def ls():
    file1=open("ls.txt","r")
    print(file1.read())
   
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    app()
```

And here is the desired output [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXext.jpg):

Comment: Please provide the output as text not image.

Answer (score 0):

I can not view the image, but I guess you want to show the tasks ordered by priority:

```py
from pathlib import Path

import typer

app = typer.Typer()
DB_NAME = "ls.txt"


@app.command()
def help():
    HELP_TEXT = """Usage :-
$ ./todo add 2 hello world  # Add a new item with priority 2 and text "hello world" to the list
$ ./todo ls               # Show incomplete priortiy list items sorted by priority in ascending order
$ ./todo del NUMBER       # Delete the incomplete item with the given priority number
$ ./todo done NUMBER      # Mark the incomplete item with given PRIORITY_NUMBER as complete
$ ./todo help             # Show usage
$ ./todo report           # Statistics """
    print(HELP_TEXT)


@app.command()
def add(priority: int, task: str):
    filepath = Path(DB_NAME)
    text = filepath.read_text()
    y = len(text.splitlines()) + 1
    with filepath.open("a") as fp:
        fp.write(f"{y}. {task} [{priority}]\n")


@app.command()
def ls():
    ss = Path(DB_NAME).read_text().splitlines()
    tasks = []
    for line in ss:
        index, tp = line.split(".", 1)
        task, priority = tp.strip("]").rsplit(" [", 1)
        tasks.append((int(priority), int(index), task.strip()))
    for priority, _, task in sorted(tasks):
        print(priority, task)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```